# How do I get 1054, "Unknown column 'carrierID_id' in 'field list'" error

Tags: mysql, django-models, django-forms

I have two models: shipping model that is having a foreign key carrierID and it is referencing the other model Carrier. When I want to add a new shipping I am getting the aforementioned error. What I know, I don't have carrierID_id field but I don't why I getting this error.

Here is the structure of my models:

```
class Carrier(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='carriers'
    carrierID=models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    carrierName=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    carrierTelephoneNumber=models.CharField(max_length=14)
    carrierAddress=models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}{}{}{}'.format(self.carrierID,' ' , self.carrierName,' ', self.carrierTelephoneNumber,' ',self.carrierAddress)


class Shipping(models.Model):
    shippingID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    carrierID = models.ForeignKey(Carrier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shippingDate = models.DateTimeField()
    productName=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    shippingAddress = models.TextField()
    sendTo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shippingStatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    promisedDate=models.DateTimeField()
    comment = models.TextField()
```

The structure of shippingForm is as below:

```
class ShippingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    carrier = Carrier.objects.only('carrierID')
    print(carrier)
    carrierID = forms.ModelChoiceField(carrier)
    shippingDate = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)
    productName = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    shippingAddress = forms.Textarea()
    sendTo = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    shippingStatus = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    promisedDate = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)
    comment = forms.Textarea()
    class Meta:
        model=Shipping
        fields=('carrierID','shippingDate', 'productName','shippingAddress', 'sendTo','shippingStatus','promisedDate', 'comment',)
```

Below are my MySQL tables:
[image: ShippingTable]
[image: CarrierTable]

Here is the SQL of the shipping.

```
create table pages_shipping(shippingID int auto_increment, 
carrierID int(11), 
shippingDate date, 
prductName varchar(50), 
shippingAddress text, 
sendTo varchar(50), 
shippingStatus boolean, 
promisedDate date, 
comment text,
primary key(shippingID), 
foreign key(carrierID) REFERENCES pages_Carrier(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Please assist

Comment: i wonder why you would use a VARCHAR for carrierID... `carrierID=models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)`.. carrierID columns have different datatypes in both tables when i look into the structures. .

Comment: @Raymond Nijland, The foreign key I'am referencing in the table shipping is the id of the carrier table.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland, any progress, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what is happening. It is because when I run `py manage.py makemigrations` command, the field carrierID is not added. Unfortunately, I don't know to force Django to add it